# How does iperf calculate throughput and jitter?

Tags: networking, bandwidth

I've read that `iperf` basically tries to send as much information down a connection as quickly as possible reporting on the throughput achieved. This tool is especially useful in determining the volume of data that links between two machines can supply.

Is it possible to gather the same results by sending regular data, as in not testing data?

What I'm trying to do is this; sending data in the foreground while in the back ground gather statistics (throughput and jitter).

So can anyone tell me how `iperf` calculates these two values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this formula defined in RFC 3550 for the RTP (Real Time Protocol). It's the same method used to calculate the Jitter in RTC:

let's say `Si` is the RTP timestamp from packet `i`, and `Ri` is the time of arrival in RTP
timestamp units for packet `i`, then for two packets `i` and `j`, `D` may be expressed as

`D(i,j) = (Rj - Ri) - (Sj - Si) = (Rj - Sj) - (Ri - Si)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--fileinput` option of `iperf` to send specific data. If you don't want to use iperf, it will get more complicated. You can use `sar` to measure network throughput, but not jitter. If you want to measure jitter yourself, you can look at [RFC 3393](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3393.txt).